# How do you inspect the type of (*) on OCaml's toplevel?

Tags: comments, ocaml

I wanted to see the type of the multiplication function (*), so I tapped it into the OCaml toplevel.

```
# (*)
```

However, the toplevel echoed:

```
(*);; 1: this is the start of a comment.
```

and then consumed any further input I put in. I figured that I had to get out of the comment mode by pressing `Ctrl+d` to send EOF. Great. But surely, I should be able to query the type of any function, including our mysterious multiplication function `(*)`?!

I would be incredibly disappointed if that is a limitation of the toplevel.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It does recognize `*)` as the end of the comment, but it's still waiting for the end of the expression. I.e. if you enter two semicolons, it will give you a syntax error and allow you to enter another expression.

To get the function `*` type `( * );;` with spaces to distinguish it from comment symbols.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that... ;) Odd to be able to do that for (+) but not for (*), and it feels like a bit of a caveat, coming from a Haskell background. Thank you though!

Comment: @Fatu Hoku - it's not really odd, it's just a short coming of the parser.  It sees `(*` and assumes a comment.  If you are familiar with C++ this is pretty much the same issue as having nested templates, where `>>` gets parsed as the operator (so you have to write `> >`).

Comment: Niki - it's not the same with the case of << : while it is possible to tell from the context of the parse whether >> should be interpreted as an operator or not (nested templates are type-level expressions, but operators are value-level), it is impossible to distinguish the beginning of a comment followed by a bracket (*) and the programmer's parenthesising of the multiplication function (*). This is a **shortcoming of the language specification**!

Comment: Ooops. Of course, in the above message, () was supposed to read (\*)